# Customizing the RadGrid EditItemTemplate Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid, rad

I created a RadGrid and added in the default edit stuff so that I can edit the data in my table. However, there is no validation for the controls that were generated and it is not very user friendly. I want to add some validation to the controls and also style them with css.

What would be the best way to go about doing this? Is it possible to add validation and styling to the controls that are automatically generated for editing columns? OR Should I create a custom template to do this?

I am just trying to get pointed in the right direction so please leave ANY feedback or insight into this!

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to create an Edit Form Template.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-edit-forms.html